# Recursive PHP function is not returning a result

Tags: php, function, nested-loops

Here is my function:

```
function loop($id) {

    unset($result, $sql, $query);
    $sql = " SELECT parent_id FROM page_entries WHERE id = '$id' ";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) or die(mysql_error());

    if ($result['parent_id'] != 0) {
        echo $result['parent_id'] . "... looping<br>";
        loop($result['parent_id']);
    } else {
        echo $result['parent_id'] . "... done loop";
        return $result['parent_id'];
    }
}

echo loop('2');
```

I'm echoing the parent_id for testing.  This is what is output to the browser:

> 1... looping
>
> 0... done loop

Where I'm not sure: the `echo loop('2')` doesn't echo anything from `return $result['id']` if I comment out the `echo` lines in the function. I've tried testing by changing the return to `return 'foo';` and still nothing.

How can I fix it?

Comment: It's not nested (that would be `function x() { function y() { } }`), it's recursive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At a glance, I think

```
loop($result['parent_id']);
```

should be

```
return loop($result['parent_id']);
```

otherwise your `if` branch is returning nothing.

Comment: always the simple things... had exact same issue, glad I came across your solution - thanks Mike. +1 for you.